Terraform cloudwatch_log_group_retention_in_days in ECS module doesn't work for CloudWatch retention setup
Target: Set the retention of CloudWatch Group to 7 days
Problem: I'm using the terraform-aws-modules/ecs and the service submodule. When I set up the retention of cloudwatch log group with setting cloudwatch_log_group_retention_in_days to 7, it doesn't work with the following code. The retention period is always 12 months as the default value.
Is the cloudwatch_log_group_retention_in_days a correct setting for this use case? Is there anything I'm missing?
module "ecs_service" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws//modules/service"

  ...
 
  container_definitions = {
    my_service = {
      essential = true
      cpu       = var.cpu
      memory    = var.memory
      image     = var.container_image
      port_mappings = [
        {
          name          = var.service_name
          containerPort = var.container_port
          protocol      = "tcp"
        }
      ]
      environment = var.environment
      readonly_root_filesystem = false

      # CloudWatch Log configuration
      enable_cloudwatch_logging              = true
      create_cloudwatch_log_group            = true
      cloudwatch_log_group_use_name_prefix   = true
      cloudwatch_log_group_name              = "/aws/ecs/my_cluster/my_service"
      cloudwatch_log_group_retention_in_days = 7
      log_configuration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
      }
    }
  }

  ...
}


Here's the documentation for that service module. Per that documentation, the entire container_definitsions block just gets passed straight to AWS by the Terraform module. Everything inside that block has to conform to this API, and anything that doesn't conform to that API is completely ignored.
The values you are trying to set are only supported by the parent module in that project. Those are top-level input variables for that module, they certainly don't belong inside a container_definitions block.
You either need to use the parent module to manage all your ECS resources, or you need to just create the CloudWatch Logs group directly, to control the settings on that resource.

Adding an opinion here: I like some of those terraform-aws-modules like the vpc and rds modules, but most of the other ones don't seem to save you much code at all, and tend to make it harder to understand what is happening than if you just directly used the Terraform AWS resources yourself.
